# Why: "identifier "vTaskDelay" is undefined"?

Tags: visual-studio-code, esp32, freertos, esp-idf

I use visual studio code with the current espressif plugin (IDF version 5.1.2). The following program can be compiled and executed on the esp32 without any problems:

```
#include <iostream>
#include "freertos/FreeRTOS.h"
#include "freertos/task.h"

#include "main.h"

void HelloCMake::run(int i)
{
    std::cout << "Hello World from C++ "<< i << '\n';
    vTaskDelay(pdMS_TO_TICKS(1000));
}

extern "C" void app_main(void)
{
    HelloCMake App;
    int i = 0;

    while (true)
    {
        App.run(i);
        i++;
    }    
}
```

However, the editor shows me the following:

1. identifier "vTaskDelay" is undefined
2. identifier "pdMS_TO_TICKS" is undefined

Why are the two problems still displayed? And how can I solve this, please?

Thanks!

Markus

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8IdRj.png)

Translated with DeepL.com (free version)

Asked Google and ChatGPT...

Comment: You had mixed of c code with c++ code.

Comment: Did you [configure the c_cpp_properties.json file](https://github.com/espressif/vscode-esp-idf-extension/blob/master/docs/C_CPP_CONFIGURATION.md)?

Answer (score 1):

you need to add esp include path to JSON file for syntax recognition in VScode editor.   Compile and IDE syntax highlight is 2 different things, IDE environment emphasis error because it does not able to find the declaration of the function, nothing to do with compile.